# msgBox / Alert with Powershell on MacOs

Tags: macos, powershell, vbscript, powershell-4.0, msgbox

I know how to make a VBS msgBox on windows

```
message = ("HELLO",0,"Title")
```

But I want to do this on Mac with Powershell

Thank you for you answers :D

Comment: Have you made any effort at all to solve this for yourself?

Comment: I assume you are running Powershell Core on your mac? I don't think the backend .NET Core has any message-boxes, you may have to call a mac-specific utility.

Comment: Yes @EBGreen. I only found solutions for windows

Comment: @user9222646: As an aside: your VBS example doesn't look like VBS.

Answer (score 6):

On macOS, you can call AppleScript's `display alert` statement, via the `osascript` CLI.

A simple example, with just an "OK" button:

```
$null = 'display alert "a title" message "a message"' | osascript
```

A more complex example with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons and storing the name of the button clicked in a variable:

```
$btnPressed = (('display alert "a title" message "a message" buttons ¬
                  { "OK", "Cancel" }' | osascript -s s) -split '"')[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can even add a variable...

$Text = "Test this variable"

$null = "display alert `"$Text`"" | osascript

Comment: there should be a ` preceding the two double quotes around $Text